# Computer draws more watts when electricity in house isn't stable?

Tags: power-supply, battery, power, ups

I have an i7 5960x (8-core, 16 threads) and two GTX 970s that are all running at full load 24/7. The total system power usage is typically around 450-550 watts when everything is under load. It has a 1000 watt power supply and is plugged into a UPS with a battery backup that is rated for 810 watts.

When the electricity in our house goes out or lights start flickering briefly (common in the spring/early summer), the UPS starts emitting a constant tone. However, rather than continuing to power the computer like I would expect, the computer still shuts off anyway, defeating the purpose of the battery backup in the UPS. I looked up what the constant tone means in the manual and it says this is because the 810 watt capacity was exceeded (so it shut off power to the computer), even though under full load the system only draws 450-550 watts (the UPS tells me this). So how does that happen?

Whenever the house has some kind of electricity problem (like it going out or lights flickering) because of a storm or whatever, is it possible that the computer can suddenly draw more watts than the 810 watt capacity? I just have no idea why this happens given the machine never gets close to 810 watts even under full GPU + CPU load when the electricity in the house is stable. It is a Thermaltake Toughpower 1000W Gold power supply and a CyberPower 810 watt battery backup UPS.

The model is LX1325G. The details here (https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/product/ups/lx1325g/) match what's on the box.

Comment: What UPS model is that exactly?

Comment: Check the documentation of your Battery Backup UPS to see the average transition time from AC to battery UPS. One of my small units is rated at about 6 ms (10 ms max). The unit may not be able to properly transition if power is flickering. You may need a true UPS instead.

Comment: Electrical devices only use the amount of power they require and no more, regardless of external forces like storms [reference Ohm's Law] _(storms can cause surges, but cannot cause more power usage)_. My hunch is your UPS isn't a pure sine wave UPS, which is likely the root of the problem, as non-pure sine wave UPS' will experience more instability and less stable performance during a power failure when drawing off the battery _(it could also be there's an issue with the battery, however computers and servers should ideally always be powered off a pure sine wave UPS)_

Comment: Does the UPS have a display that indicates how long it will run on the load it detects?  This could be a simple problem as the battery needs to be replaced.  Much easier for you to indicate if your UPS as the display than me trying to find a screenshot of your UPS

Comment: Please provide the exact make and model of all relevant hardware. CyberPower has dozens of different models.

Comment: The computer might be momentarily (for a few miliseconds) be drawing the total 1000W of inrush current, as a side effect of PFC, which your PSU has. This is beacuse there is a moment (around 10ms is typical) when the transition is ocurring that power is shut off tho the PSU, causing it to draw inrush current as if it was being powered on for the first time. It is possible that the UPS can't handle that momentary current and overloads. [Schneider Electric recommends a UPS with 125% the capacity of your PSU](https://www.se.com/ww/en/faqs/FA158939/) (that would be 1250W)

Comment: As mentioned, likely the UPS battery is getting weak. Lead-acid batteries usually last five to seven years, gradually losing storage and *maximum current* capacity. It's possible to replace the battery even on sealed units, though it may require cutting open the case. Also, connect only essential items to the UPS, e.g. PC and external HDD. Losing the display is a nuisance, but reduces current draw.

Comment: @Daniel B, I have updated my post with the exact model.